# Secure snowflake python connector

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, connector

I am trying to connect to snowflake from my laptop using the python connector. The problem is that my company has strict rules on connections and transferring data.
I couldn't find anything in their documentation on securing data transfer.
Anyone has done it at a company to help me with a solution that I can offer to our IT team?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by “securing data transfer”? Authorisation/authentication to Snowflake? The network connection? Something else?

Comment: Python connector uses HTTPS protocol to connect from the client side (your laptop) to Snowflake so traffic is encrypted. What kind of rules your company has on connections and transferring data?

Comment: My manager said they had a lot of stories connecting it with data robot and still they cannot use all databases in datarobot. Only some. I will contact our IT and see what will happen. Thanks

Comment: What are you asking exactly, If transferring data is secure? I think you might need to take some time to understand what you need, your question isn't fully formed.

Comment: @SimonD  Basic HTTPs Data transfer over the internet is not considered secured by many companies.

Comment: Including your company?